# Checking for date range in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a booking system for a beauty salon. I have tables of:

Providers - the workers at the salon.

```
TABLE `providers` (
  `providerId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `providerName` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`providerId`)
)

101 Anna
102 Beata
```

Services - different services they offer

```
TABLE `services` (
  `serviceId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `service` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `serviceDuration` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `providerId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`serviceId`)
)

1   Hair cut    30  101
2   Hair coloring   120 101
```

Schedule - a table over when different services are offered per provider

```
TABLE `schedule` (
  `scheduleId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `serviceId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `providerId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `scheduleStartDateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `scheduleEndDateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`scheduleId`)
)

1   1   101 2014-10-17 10:00:00 2014-10-17 10:29:59
2   1   101 2014-10-17 10:30:00 2014-10-17 10:59:59
3   1   101 2014-10-17 11:00:00 2014-10-17 11:29:59
4   1   101 2014-10-17 11:30:00 2014-10-17 11:59:59
5   1   101 2014-10-17 12:00:00 2014-10-17 12:29:59
6   2   101 2014-10-17 10:30:00 2014-10-17 12:29:59
```

And finally, a Bookings - a table of the booked services.

```
TABLE `bookings` (
  `bookingId` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `clientId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bookingDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `serviceId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `providerId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `startDateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `endDateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bookingId`)
)

1   1   2014-10-16  1   101 2014-10-17 10:30:00 2014-10-17 10:59:59
```

There are of course more tables for Clients, Payments etc that are joined
into the searches.

My problem is the search to find the non-booked available services per provider.

Let say someone want a hair cut by Anna. I then would like to present the available scheduled times for hair cutting, excluding the already booked one at 10:30:00.

```
select s.serviceId, s.providerId, s.scheduleStartDateTime, s.scheduleEndDateTime
FROM schedule AS s
WHERE s.serviceId = '1'
AND s.providerId NOT IN
(
    SELECT providerId
    FROM bookings
    WHERE startDateTime <= s.scheduleEndDateTime 
    AND endDateTime >= s.scheduleStartDateTime
)
```

But this search give this result:

```
1   101 2014-10-17 10:00:00 2014-10-17 10:29:59
1   101 2014-10-17 10:30:00 2014-10-17 10:59:59  <-- This should not show up
1   101 2014-10-17 11:00:00 2014-10-17 11:29:59
1   101 2014-10-17 11:30:00 2014-10-17 11:59:59
1   101 2014-10-17 12:00:00 2014-10-17 12:29:59
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e5f22

Comment: Can you explain, why this record should not be shown?

Comment: @Jens Er, because the bookings table already has a booking for 10.30 !?!

Comment: It is already booked, and have an entry in the bookings table

Comment: @RolandJohansson You're so close to providing proper DDLs, why not go the whole hog and do so (and/or an sqlfiddle)?

Comment: I don't understand why using where clause like this :
WHERE startDateTime <= s.scheduleEndDateTime 
    AND endDateTime >= s.scheduleStartDateTime

If i'm right, i think that the compared value should be a user defined value, so your where clause will be : 

    s.scheduleEndDateTime >= '2014-10-17 10:30:00'
    s.scheduleStartDateTime <= '2014-10-17 10:30:00'

Comment: @Anas I want to show the scheduled times. That's why I compare the schedule times with the booked times. The user have to choose a scheduled time.
They are not free to enter any user defined value

Comment: so, you want to select available service/provider times ?

Comment: @Anas "Let say someone want a hair cut by Anna. I then would like to present the available scheduled times for hair cutting, excluding the already booked one at 10:30:00."

Comment: see my answer, i think your where clause in subquery was wrong

Comment: After fixing the wrong date I put in the bookings table in the sqlfiddle the original version work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the correct answer in the sqlfiddle (after changing the wrong date I put in the bookings table).
I had the same error in my original table. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

I think your SQL should be like this :

```html
select s.serviceId, s.providerId, s.scheduleStartDateTime, s.scheduleEndDateTime
FROM schedule AS s
WHERE s.serviceId = '1'
AND s.providerId NOT IN
(
    SELECT b.providerId
    FROM bookings AS b
    WHERE b.startDateTime >= s.scheduleEndDateTime 
    AND b.endDateTime <= s.scheduleStartDateTime
)
```

The subquery should select the the booked ones, so the main query will exclude these booked.

Anas

Comment: I apologize, I put the wrong date in the sqlfiddle...
My original version work now
But your version do not

Comment: Ok, Congratulations :)

Answer (score 0):

The schedule table seems odd to me.  Are you planning to pre-generate rows in the schedule table for each day?  If so, then the bookings table would only need to store a schedule id for the booked time slot, but it gets more difficult as services are not all the same length.

It seems like the schedule concept can be simplified.  You need to know what time each provider starts and stops their day.  Then you can schedule the services at a particular start time, going for the length of the duration (30 minutes or 120 minutes).  The start time and duration is what blocks off the providers schedule.

When a customer wants to create a booking, they can choose from the available start times (every 30 minutes) with a long enough duration (i.e. the openings in the providers schedule).  The search query can retrieve the existing bookings, and then you can limit the customer's choices on the display side.

Comment: The idea for the schedule table is to pre-schedule the services offered by the providers. They do not offer all services every day, based on personal taste, I guess. So I wanted to combine the schedule for the providers as well as their services. I was thinking to copy from weekly templates. 

But the problem was why the search does not turn out like I want...